# how to remove squid to work as nat that already configured in ubuntu?

Tags: proxy, iptables, squid

I'm running `squid3` in my Ubuntu 14.04 and tried remote proxy use for study purposes . When I try remote access with another computer in the University LAN, I encounter empty cache log. So I have tried

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

Then my squid is stop working, soon after starting. How can I revert the changes which I made using the above command??

Comment: Close Voters, what is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

With `sudo iptables -t nat --line-numbers -L` you should see something like this:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 3128

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Remove the `PREROUTING` rule(s) affecting port `3128`:

```
sudo iptables -t nat --line-numbers -L | tac | \
    awk '/redir ports 3128/ {system("sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING "$1)}'
```

Now check the rules again:

```
% sudo iptables -t nat --line-numbers -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

---

*Explanation*

`iptables -vt nat -L` lists the needed rules

```
% sudo iptables -vt nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 11 packets, 1957 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 3128

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 194 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 152 packets, 14386 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 152 packets, 14386 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

And we need the rules for port `3128` in reverse order, if you have more than one, and the line-numbers

```
% sudo iptables -t nat --line-numbers -L | tac | awk '/redir ports 3128/'
1    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 3128
```

a little bit `awk` magic deletes the rules line by line

```
awk '/redir ports 3128/ {system("sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING "$1)}'
```